# Azure Functions - Python - Visual Studio Code

Tags: python, azure, visual-studio-code, azure-functions

I am trying to execute the Hello World code in Azure Functions.
I am invoking the python code - Blog Storage trigger in Azure Function from Visual Studio Code.

I have not done any changes in init.py.
I am getting the below error:

```
Found Python version 3.8.0 (py).
Azure Functions Core Tools (3.0.2881 Commit hash: fa9641ad925588192888bc977ff****************)
Function Runtime Version: 3.0.14287.0
A host error has occurred during startup operation '7bad93bb-xxxx-4da0-9461-55fc9deaxxxx'.
System.Net.Http: Error while copying content to a stream. System.Net.Security:  Received an unexpected EOF or 0 bytes from the transport stream.  
Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'provider')
Application is shutting down...
The terminal process "C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -Command .venv\Scripts\activate ; func host start" terminated with exit code: 1.
```

Any help on what has to be done to fix this? Thanks.

Comment: What operating system are you using? Asking because of this github thread = https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-core-tools/issues/2154

Comment: And one more here = https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-core-tools/issues/2157

Comment: I use windows 10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have not change anything in the code, then your function should work after upload to azure.

The error seems related with the tls version.

If you just want to test it briefly, you can create a python-based function app directly on Azure.

If you are using a blob trigger, it will actually tranform data into a stream. Therefore, the simulation can be done using ordinary python scripts, you only need to put it in the function body of the azure function after the simulation is completed.

In addition, I still hope you can show the code and configuration files. (If there is no problem, it should work well on Azure, and the problem should be local.)